# Javascript click position off

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm currently trying to click inside of a grid that I have created. Where I click I want it to draw a hook at that clicked location. Currently it is drawing but not at the location I clicked. Here is a stack snippit showing what I have. Also the code snipit is the function that draws the hook.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
    const batman = document.createElement('div')
    const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
    grid.addEventListener("click", grappleHook , false)
    const hook = document.createElement('div')
    let batmanLeftSpace = 50
    let batmanBottomSpace = 150
    let isGamOver = false
    let grappleBottom= 0
    let grappleLeft = 0
    let isFalling

    // class Platform{
    //     constructor(newPlatBottom){
    //         this.left = Math.random() * 750
    //         this.visual = document.createElement('div')
    //         const visual = this.visual
    //         visual.classList.add('platform')
    //         visual.style.left = this.left + 'px'
    //         visual.style.bottom = this.bottom + 'px'
    //         grid.appendChild(visual)
    //     }
    // }


    function createBatman(){
        grid.appendChild(batman)
        batman.classList.add('batman')
        batman.style.left = batmanLeftSpace + 'px'
        batman.style.bottom = batmanBottomSpace + 'px'
    }

    function grappleHook(e){
        grid.appendChild(hook)
        grappleBottom = e.clientY
        grappleLeft = e.clientX
        console.log("X: " + grappleLeft + " Y: " + grappleBottom)
        hook.classList.add('hook')
        hook.style.left = grappleLeft + 'px'
         hook.style.bottom = grappleBottom + 'px'
    }

    function start(){
        if(!isGamOver){
            createBatman()
        }
    }

    start()
})
```

```css
.grid{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 850px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
}

.batman{
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.hook{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' dir='ltr'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Bat Grappler</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
        <script src= "index.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class ="game_container">
            <div class ="grid">

            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to set the style of `hook` to `position: absolute;`

Comment: You should also declare the variables `reappleBottom` and `grappleLeft` local to the function.

Comment: I do have the position set absolute. I forgot to show my css classList I'll add that in now.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Just posted picture sampling my issue

Comment: Not a picture. Post the code so we can try to run it.

Comment: `grid{` should be `.grid{`

Comment: yeah, That's my bad that just a typo on stackOverFlow. I'll fix it now. I know that's not the issue because it's still drawing the grid in the background which is just where the game that I'm making will be. Good eye though!

Comment: Why won't you create a Stack Snippet?

Comment: That's my bad. I'm new and misunderstood what you were saying. I have updated it now hopefully this is along the lines of what you wanted. Sorry and thanks for being patient.

Comment: Why did you use jsfiddle instead of Stack Snippet? If you don't know how, I gave you a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are little change need in your function `grappleHook` like `hook.style.bottom` ==> `hook.style.top` and it will working as you want

**Try It**

```
function grappleHook(e){
      grid.appendChild(hook)
      console.dir(grid);
      grappleBottom = e.clientY
      grappleLeft = e.clientX
      console.log("X: " + grappleLeft + " Y: " + grappleBottom)
      hook.classList.add('hook')
      hook.style.left = ( grappleLeft - grid.offsetLeft) + 'px'
      hook.style.top = ( grappleBottom - grid.offsetTop) + 'px'
}
```

**CSS**

```
.hook {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: I just gave that a go. But the issue still remains. I'm thinking that the click coordinates are messed up somehow due to me clicking inside of that grid. But I don't know

Comment: You want to show black box inside red box ?

Comment: I want the black box to show inside of the blue box (it is showing inside the blue box now but not where i click.). The blue box is the grid. I want everything inside that grid. The red will be the character(batman) in the game. The black box is the grapple hook at the clicked loaction

Comment: Did you replace `grappleHook` function definition?

Comment: Yeah, I did. It seemed to help with the y coordinates of the click. But the x Value is still a ways off.  Where ever you click hook has a pretty big gap to the right between where you clicked and where the hook is drawn

Comment: I just subtracted 200 to the left style and it seems to be lining up now with my cick like this -> hook.style.left = grappleLeft  - 200 + 'px' But what would the reasoning of it being of by this much be?

Comment: I just updated my answer `grappleHook` updated now

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know the offset was a thing:P